# Get id if the text match with array

Tags: php, arrays, function, filter

I need the Id if the 'Final' text match on this array. Like this for array one `288617` and for array two `288031`.

```
Array
(
    [0] => a:4:{i:0;s:11:"Demo Course";i:1;s:6:"288616";i:2;s:10:"Final Exam";i:3;s:6:"288617";}
)

Array
(
    [0] => a:29:{i:0;s:16:"Sage 50 Accounts";i:1;s:6:"287967";i:2;s:6:"278823";i:3;s:6:"278824";i:4;s:6:"278825";i:5;s:6:"278826";i:6;s:6:"278856";i:7;s:6:"278857";i:8;s:6:"278858";i:9;s:6:"278859";i:10;s:6:"278860";i:11;s:6:"278861";i:12;s:6:"278862";i:13;s:6:"279608";i:14;s:6:"279609";i:15;s:6:"279610";i:16;s:6:"279611";i:17;s:6:"278821";i:18;s:6:"279612";i:19;s:6:"279613";i:20;s:6:"279681";i:21;s:6:"279677";i:22;s:6:"279678";i:23;s:6:"279679";i:24;s:6:"279680";i:25;s:9:"Mock Exam";i:26;s:6:"288030";i:27;s:10:"Final Exam";i:28;s:6:"288031";}
)
```

I have tried with this code, but can't work.

```
$search_text = 'Final';
    array_filter($array, function($el) use ($search_text) {
            return ( strpos($el['text'], $search_text) !== false );
        });
```

Comment: according to that dump above, you don't have index `$el['text']`. only index zero

Comment: Your subarrays are serialized. Unserialize them first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to `unserialize` that text.  Then the simplest way is to loop and check for the text and then take the next element:

```
$array[0] = unserialize($array[0]);

$search_text = 'Final';

foreach($array[0] as $key => $value){ 
    if(strpos($value, $search_text) !== false) {
        $result = $array[0][$key+1];
        break;
    }
}
```

This assumes that the array is paired the way you have shown:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Demo Course
    [1] => 288616
    [2] => Final Exam
    [3] => 288617
)
```

With your second array it would only return the first ID `287967` if you search on `Sage`.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I have tried by this code, but not showed any result. can you please check? Maybe I have missed something. `$array = $meta['vibe_course_curriculum'];
  $array[0] = unserialize($array[0]);

  $search_text = 'Final';

  foreach($array[0] as $key => $value){ 
   if(strpos($value, $search_text) !== false) {
    $result = $array[0][$key+1];
    break;
   }
  }`

Comment: If `$meta['vibe_course_curriculum']` is the ouput that you show in the question then https://3v4l.org/ODLIT

Answer (score 0):

Try `end` function.
This function return the last element of your array

```
$array = ['sample1', 'sample2', ... ,'Final';
$search_text = 'Final';

if(end($aray) == $search_text){
    // find
}else{
   // not found
}
```

Comment: `$arr = $meta['vibe_course_curriculum'];
  $search_text = 'Final';

  if(end($arr) == $search_text){
   echo 'Found <br>';
  }else{
   echo 'Not Found <br>';
  }` not worked

Comment: if your array is `serialize`; please at first `unserialize` the array